# Create a SharePoint Document Library with Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to create a new document library in a SharePoint Teams site using Microsoft Graph.

```cs
var docLibrary = $@"{{ ""name"": ""{listName}"", ""list"": {{ ""template"": ""documentLibrary"" }} }}";
var res = await GraphClient.QueryGraphAsyncPost($"/groups/{groupId}/sites/root/lists/", docLibrary, user);
var result = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This is the code that I'm using, but it is returning a bad request.  I can't seem to find in the documentation the correct way to create a Document Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to specify the `displayName` instead of the `name`. The value of `name` is generated by the server, and so the 400 is an error saying it cannot be written to. You should see an error response that contains the following message:

> Cannot define a 'name' for a list as it is assigned by the server. Instead, provide 'displayName'

If you change your request to the following it should work:

```
var docLibrary = $@"{{ ""displayName"": ""{listName}"", ""list"": {{ ""template"": ""documentLibrary"" }} }}";
var res = await GraphClient.QueryGraphAsyncPost($"/groups/{groupId}/sites/root/lists", docLibrary, user);
var result = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: For me unable to find  QueryGraphAsyncPost  in GraphServiceClient object Can someone please tell me which class method of QueryGraphAsyncPost ?